# Google Sheets multiple nested ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Does multiple nested ArrayFormula's have any effect in any circumstances? For example `arrayformula(...arrayformula(...arrayformula(...)))`

Answer (score 0):

no, it does not. in fact, it's pointless to nest arrayformulae. ArrayFormula should be always wrapping the most outer part of your functions and therefore included only once

Comment: True, except for when you are working with functions that of themselves output an array such as mmult you might want the arrayformula inside a function. I was just wondering if there was some crazy edge case where nesting an arrayformula in another arrayformula actually might change the behavior.